# Formula to pull cell from rightmost column with data (knowing row number)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a formula that I can use to pull a number from the rightmost column with data?  The row will never change and length of the column range is already predefined.  I will just be adding data in each column over time and would like the most recent number to appear in a separate cell.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. If you input data in row 1, you can use:

```
=INDEX(1:1,MATCH(9^99,1:1,1))
```

Or

```
=LOOKUP(9^99,1:1)
```

To get the most recent *number*. Those won't work with text, but you can replace `9^99` with `zzz` for text.

If you can have a number larger than the result of `9^99` though, you need to pick a higher number in the above formulae.

Comment: Awesome the first one you mentioned worked like a charm.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: one more question, is there any way to set it so that the number it pulls has to be greater than 0?  I don't have blank columns but do have some that have 0's in them.  Not a big deal if it's not an easy adjustment.  It's not necessary

Comment: @user2094096 Sure, replace the range in the lookup function (i.e. either MATCH or LOOKUP) to `IF(1:1>0,1:1)`. Just change the range accordingly. You'll have to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of Enter alone however, since this becomes an array formula.

Comment: If you use this version `=LOOKUP(2,1/(1:1>0),1:1)` that will give you the last value > 0 without CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Answer (score 1):

For row 3, assuming there are no blanks left of the last column with data:

```
=INDEX(3:3,1,COUNTA(3:3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for numbers and strings and ignores blanks. It's an array formula, so must be entered with ctrl-shift-enter:

```
=INDEX(2:2,MAX((2:2<>"")*(COLUMN(2:2))))
```